# Non-maintainer uploads to Hackage

Tags: haskell, hackage

I have a package on Hackage which depends on third-party package, which doesn't build on newer versions of GHC (>= 7.2). The problem with the other package can be solved with just a one-line patch (a `LANGUAGE` pragma). I sent the patch to the upstream twice, but didn't receive any feedback. The problem is that my package is not installable neither until the dependency is fixed.

I could have uploaded the fixed version of depenency package (with a minor version bump), but I'd like to hear what is the attitude of the community about such non-maintainer uploads. Again, I don't want to change the library interface, I only add a new compilation flag to make it buildable again.

- Are non-maintainer uploads to Hackage allowed and tolerated?
- When a fork of the package on Hackage is a better approach?

Comment: While this is an important question, I'm not sure this is the best place for this debate. Maybe the libraries list would be better, or haskell-cafe?

Comment: I don't read haskell-cafe, re-subscribing to just ask a question is too much hassle. Also people can upvote answers on SO, which is a good way to learn about community consensus (after some time), and new answers may appear, but people rarely answer in the mailing list after few days.

Comment: Perhaps we should make a page on the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) addressing this question.

Comment: There has been a recent discussion on haskell-cafe about streamlining the ownership change process: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/SlWfpCabuR0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package uploads by non-maintainers are allowed (there may be license issues, but most packages if not all on hackage have licenses permitting this), but of course they are not usually done. They are tolerated if done in good faith and with reasonable procedure. If you contact the maintainer and don't get any response within n weeks (where I'm not sure what the appropriate value of n is, not less than 3, I'd say), uploading a new version yourself becomes an option, discussing that on the mailing lists seems however more prudent. If the package looks like it is abandoned, even taking over maintainership - of course after again contacting the maintainer, giving her/him time to respond - may be the appropriate action, but that should definitely be discussed with the community (haskell-cafe or mailing list, for example). Whether to prefer a non-maintainer upload or a fork must be left to your judgment, personally I tend to believe forks step on fewer people's toes.

But a better founded reply would be possible if we knew which package is concerned and could look at the concrete situation.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait until a month expires, then ask on the mailing list before uploading. The package doesn't look abandoned, it received two major version updates in 2011, and several minor version bumps.

Answer (score 5):

A forking is *intrusive* for a package that you suspect is still maintained but the author is temporarily missing. By intrusive, I mean that other programmers might pick up your fork then not go back to the mainline once the original author has resumed work on the mainline.

For packages where the original author has left the Haskell community, my personal opinion is that its better to fork the package if you are going to develop it further. Forking prevents succession problems, such as those that happened with Parsec where many developers didn't want to update because the successor was slower and less well documented than the original for some time.

In all cases asking on the Cafe is best, regardless of whether people have chosen not to follow it, it is still the center of the Haskell community.

For the particular case in the question, while it is nice if things on Hackage compile, there is no rule that says they have to. A package that depends on a broken package could simply put change instructions for the broken dependency on its front page, i.e. *"This package depends on LambdaThing-0.2.0 which is broken, to fix LambdaThing add ... to the file Lambda.hs"*

Answer (score 2):

I would say, it's a very good idea to consult the mailing lists regarding the specific package and the specific person who is missing. I took control of the haskell-src-meta package from its original owner, but only after consulting with the lists and IRC, who assured me that Matt Morrow had been missing for months and no-one knew why.

In my opinion, package ownership should probably only be changed where there is a consensus to do so, or at the very least there should be efforts made to find one. In the development version of the Hackage software, it's my understanding there are access controls so that only administrators can make this kind of intervention.